# Return value from inner scope in a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a function, with a "then" function nestled inside with a return. I want this return to be added to the outer return. See code:

```
public async getAllWidgets(): Promise <Widget[]> {
  let settings = new SettingsRepository(this.context, null);

  let data: Widget[];

  settings.CountryUrl().then(async(url) => {
    var repositoryUserCountryUrl = new ListRepository(url);
    var cacheKey = "QuickLinksLinksAllWidgets";
    let widgets: any[];

    let multiLingual = await settings.MultiLingual(this.absoluteWebUrl);

    if (multiLingual) {
      let currentLanguage = await Languages.getLanguage(this.context, null, this.absoluteWebUrl);
      cacheKey += "-" + currentLanguage;
      widgets = await repositoryUserCountryUrl.getListItemsByUrlLanguageAware(Constants.QuickLinksListUrl, `local-${cacheKey}`, currentLanguage);
    } else {
      widgets = await repositoryUserCountryUrl.getListItemsByUrl(Constants.QuickLinksListUrl, `local-${cacheKey}`);
    }

    let result: Widget[] = [];
    widgets.map((item) => {
      result.push(this.parseWidget(item));
    });

    let data: Widget[] = result;

    return data; /// HAVE ALL THE DATA I NEED

  });

  return new Promise <Widget[]> (async(resolve) => {
    console.log("data in return" + data)
    resolve(data); /// UNDEFINED DATA
  });
}
```

When I call the above function, I don't get anything, even if the first inner return contains data so my guess I have to add that to the outer return somehow. How can I do it?

Comment: Just get rid of the `return new Promise`, and just `return settings.CountryUrl().then(....`

Comment: Use settings.CountryUrl() function in another function which returns a promise, and in that promise you need to resolve data that you need. So that you will be able to return both url and data or whatever you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap your whole function in the new promise, not only at the end like you are doing, and then resolve the data variable. You can't return from inside an async and expect it not to be undefined because the function runs normally and ends before the data has been loaded.

So...

```
public async getAllWidgets(): Promise<Widget[]>  {
    return new Promise((resolve, error) => {
      // your data calculations...
      resolve(data)
    }
}
```